# Jquery Accordian CSS header color changes based on IF then

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, css

I basically know how to create a JQuery accordion and can insert my MSSQL Data has the header But I am wanting to change the color of the header based on column data.
    @{var db = Database.Open("DB");
    var commstat = "SELECT [name],[time],[state] FROM [dbo].[COMMLINE_STATUS]";
    }

```
  $(function () {

      $("#accordion").accordion();

  });
```

@foreach (var ms in db.Query(commstat)){

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3><a href="#">@ms.name</a></h3>
<div>
<p>@ms.time</p>
</div>}
```

Based on the state which is up or down I want the color of the accordion box to be greenish for up and reddish for down.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put something like `ui-accordion-content-active` in your CSS and style that (green), while using `ui-accordion-content` for the red? jQuery is already using classes on the accordion elements.